# AWS boto3. How do I launch EC2 instance into a given cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to create an ECS cluster and then proceed to launch an EC2 instance into that cluster. However this is not happening.

My code:

```
ecs_client = boto3.client(
    'ecs',
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    region_name=region
)

ec2_client = boto3.client(
    'ec2',
    aws_access_key_id=access_key,
    aws_secret_access_key=secret_key,
    region_name=region
)

response = ecs_client.create_cluster(
    clusterName=cluster_name
)

response = ec2_client.run_instances(
    # Use the official ECS image
    ImageId="ami-0128839b21d19300e",
    MinCount=1,
    MaxCount=1,
    InstanceType="t2.micro",
    IamInstanceProfile={
        "Name": "ecsInstanceRole"
    },
    UserData="#!/bin/bash \n echo ECS_CLUSTER=" + cluster_name + " >> /etc/ecs/ecs.config"
)
```

the ecsInstanceRole

From what I've read, the UserData should make this possible but it is not at the moment.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Any error messages? Instance does not launch, any timeout, UserData does not execute?

Comment: No error messages. Cluster is created, instance is launched, User Data is written into the ecs.config file on the instance but apparently not executed as the instance does not appear in the cluster

Comment: Does your instance has internet access?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to **replicate** you issue in `us-east-1`, but your `boto3` code **works** fine. I had no problems creating a cluster and launching an instance using your boto3 script to that cluster. You code, by default will launch an instance in a default VPC.

Thus, the **fault must be outside** of the code provided. A possible cases could be misconstrued default VPC, custom changes to `ecsInstanceRole` role permissions or lack connectivity to ECS service